# maximum sum of two subset standard deviation

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

Given a finite set defined in real number $\{x \mid 0< x < 1 \}$ with size $N > 3$

If I split $\{x\}$ into two subsets $\{A\}$ and $\{B\}$ , $A\cup B = X$ and $A\cap B =  \emptyset $, How can i find the special subsets, which have maximum $Std(A)+Std(B)$.

${\displaystyle Std={\sqrt {\frac {\sum _{i=1}^{N}(x_{i}-{\overline {x}})^{2}}{N-1}}}.}$

Comment: Do you mean finite rather than countable?

Comment: And what do you do for the case $N=1$?

Comment: ah yes yes, i mean finite, and N>3, and thank you!!!

Comment: Well, if your set isn't too big you could use brute force.

Comment: yes yes, i'm wondering is there any method better than brute force? even some kind of dynamic programming would be a great help. or with some probabilistic help

Comment: It appears (at least I haven't found a counterexample) that the optimal split has one of $A$ and $B$ consisting of two elements.